# UIMenuController is not visible in iOS 13.2

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I have long press handler that shows `UIMenuController`, it works as usual on < ios13.2, for example on 13.1 it works fine, but on ios13.2 it's not shown, here's methods that I had:

```
private func longPressHandler(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard
        sender.state == .began,
        let senderView = sender.view,
        let superView = sender.view?.superview
    else {
        return
    }

    senderView.becomeFirstResponder()

    UIMenuController.shared.setTargetRect(senderView.frame, in: superView)
    UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}

private func makeMenuController() {
    UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [
        UIMenuItem(title: "ui.report".localized, action: ChatCustomMenuItems.report),
        UIMenuItem(title: "ui.chat.reply".localized, action: ChatCustomMenuItems.reply),
        UIMenuItem(title: "ui.action.block".localized, action: ChatCustomMenuItems.block)
    ]
}
```

In the documentation I've found out that setTargetRect and setMenuVisible are deprecated
[image]

Changing like this, still doesn't help. Any solution?

```swift
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    UIMenuController.shared.isMenuVisible = true
    UIMenuController.shared.showMenu(from: superView, rect: senderView.frame)
} else {
    UIMenuController.shared.setTargetRect(senderView.frame, in: superView)
    UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Have test in iOS 14.0?, It seems not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem! The problem can be caused by not calling

```
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

or calling it before `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

Comment: In iOS 14 it's still not showing menu.
I have used UIMenuController.shared.showMenu(from: superView, rect: senderView.frame), But not working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to call `becomeFirstResponder` to make the menu showing:

```
window?.makeKey()
becomeFirstResponder()
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure that you don't create other instances of UIMenuController in your code, like this **let menu = UIMenuController()**

Answer (score -1):

Before that you should override the property like this:

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool{
    get{
        return true
    }
}
```

Then it will work.