# Copy/paste UIMenuItem not showing in all my application

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uisearchbar, uimenucontroller

I have a problem that occurs in all my application (minimum target iOS13): there's no UIMenuController displayed, neither in UISearchBar nor in UITextFieald.

I tried to subclass a UITextField and override canPerformAction, the func is triggered, i return true but nothing happen..

can anyone help, thanks.

Comment: Can you add codes related to that functions

Comment: @Kalana please look to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the call of "window.makeKeyAndVisible()" in the sceneDelegate

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }        
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.rootViewController = TabBarController()
        // i delete this line and the UIMenuController are displayed ! 
        -> window.makeKeyAndVisible()<-
        self.window = window
        self.window?.windowScene =  windowScene
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Comment: If you search little more bit in stack overflow you could have find that answer. Look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176844/uimenucontroller-is-not-visible-in-ios-13-2

Comment: the accepted comment advice to call the func, but i had to remove it to make it work ..

Comment: Yes, that is kind of opposite thing.

Comment: Add your previous code which before you find the answer to you question unless your question will be close because of fewer details

Comment: Please also add the reasons why this works. It would be beneficial for all of us.